# Hightlighting the link of the current page

Tags: css, html, nav

I'm having trouble highlighting the currently selected link on the displayed page. I'm using HTML5 and CSS only. I've found that it works when I change id in every html-document to "currentLink", but only by using the traditional class/id like so:

```
#y.x {
   /* will select element of id="y" that also has class="x" */
}
```

However, to make the entire link element clickable, I have used "nav", which seems to be incompatible with the solution above.

This is my index page HTML:

```
        <nav>
            <div id="currentLink" class="buttons">
                <a href="index.html">Om oss</a>
            </div>
            <div id="buttonVarahundar" class="buttons">
                <a href="">Våra hundar</a>
            </div>
            <div id="buttonValpar" class="buttons">
                <a href="">Valpar</a>
            </div>
            <div id="buttonKontakt" class="buttons">
                <a href="contact.html">Kontakt</a>
            </div>          
        </nav>
```

And the CSS:

```
nav a {
    display: block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 3em;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 8%;
    padding-right: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 4%;
    padding-left: 0%;   
    background-color: #CCFFCC;  
    box-shadow: 0.2em -0.2em 10px #303030;          
    border-radius: 1em 1em 0 0; 
}

nav a #currentLink .buttons {
    background-color: #E0FFFF;      
    box-shadow: 0.2em -0.2em 10px #303030, 0 0.2em #FFFFFF;
}
```

What I'm doing is replacing some colours and shadow to create the visuals that I want. Do you have any idea how this can work with the first method, but not my own?

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
nav a #currentLink .buttons {
```

by

```
nav div#currentLink.buttons a {
```

Comment: There is no need (and bad practice) to use div#currentLink.buttons. #currentLink.buttons should be sufficient since their should only be one tag with id currentLink. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS#Don.27t_qualify_ID-categorized_rules_with_tag_names_or_classes

Comment: I decided to go with "nav #currentLink a", which works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

The spaces in the selector represent different elements

"`#page1 nav a`" will select all links (a), that have parent element `nav`, that are located in element with ID `page`.

All this selectors will work for your case:

```
<style>
nav div#currentLink.buttons a {...}
nav #currentLink.button a {...}
nav #currentLink a {...}
div#currentLink.button a {...}
#currentLink.button a {...}
#currentLink a {...}
```

In general you should use ID (`#`) for elements that are unique on your page like:
"`#logo`, `#heade`, `#main-menu`, `#unicorn`".
Classes  (`.`) are used for markups and commonly repeated elements:
"`.button`, `.title` `.selected`"

to keep your css clean and readable try to construct selectors  with "closest 'Named' element(with ID) + the shortest possible UNIQUE combination of classes and elements selectors"

so in the from the above examples `#currentLink a` is the perfect selector for the job.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a class to the link that is currently selected:

```
<nav>
<div id="currentLink" class="buttons">
<a href="index.html" class="active">Om oss</a>
</div>
<div id="buttonVarahundar" class="buttons">
<a href="">Våra hundar</a>
</div>
</nav>
```

So the CSS for the links would be:

```
nav a {
/* your styles */ 
}
```

And some CSS for the selected link, when every selected link should look the same:

```
nav a.active {
/* your styles */
}
```

When every selected link should look different, you will have to get more specific:

```
#currentlink a.active {
/* Styles for #currentlink when it is the selected*/
}
#buttonVarahundar a.active {
/* Styles for #buttonVarahundar when it is the selected link */
}
```